# how gmail accepts usernames

Tags: css, html, gmail

Recently i looked at the **gmail's** input filed. it has the following **html** syntax(found it using firebug)

```
<input id="Email" name="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" value="" spellcheck="false" class="">
```

Here, my doubt is, the above input field has **type="email"** attribute. But it accepts **usernames** also.  Suppose if my email address is **johnsmith@gmail.com** i can login using name **johnsmith** without typing **@gmail.com**. How it is possible ? i should get a syntax error right ?

i googled it. but din't find any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML 5 if you want to disable client side validation for a form add a `novalidate` attribute to the form element. as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo" novalidate> ....</form>
```

Google has also disbaled form validation see below line in google code

```
<form novalidate="" method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth" id="gaia_loginform">
```

Click to read more  on [HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-novalidate)

Comment: Thank u very much. it is working fine. Can i use novalidate attribute for inputs? or only for forms ?